# Debugging with Android Studio: Two different kinds of breakpoints

Tags: android, debugging

Working with Android Studio, I debug my app using breakpoints. There seem to be two kinds of breakpoints:

[image]
[image]

Could someone explain the difference between those two breakpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official JetBrains Help, the Breakpoint without the small tick means that the breakpoint is **enabled** and the other with the small tick means that the breakpoint is **valid**.

For more information, see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/breakpoints-icons-and-statuses.html

Comment: Can you give an example of a case where the break point is invalid?

Comment: A breakpoint on a line with a catch(Exception e) will be an invalid breakpoint.
Also, a breakpoint on a line that will never be hit, e.g, a line after a return statement (there will be a compilation error, anyway) is also an invalid breakpoint. Another e.g is a breakpoint in a function that's never called.

Comment: INVALID breakpoints have "x" on them. What about empty breakpoints, as asked in the question?